# French-English dictionaries with literal translations in them

Tags: dictionnaires

I want to learn French. I thought it would be helpful to know literal translations, so where can I find a bilingual dictionary with such entries?

I think that the best way to learn french is to learn literal translations, but even with something like il y a that’s hard to find any examples?

Comment: There may be an existing question about this somewhere, but I'm having trouble digging it up. Wiktionary is helpful, but it's over-simplistic. Personally, I always end up double-checking with the French version of the site or with TLFi. Larousse has bilingual dictionaries online, which can be a useful reference.

Comment: Like I know il y a means there is, but literally it’s it has there, but I can’t find a dictionary that says that

Comment: Even Larousse says that

Comment: As grammatical analysis, that may be useful, and some dictionary or textbook may even describe the literal meaning. It may also help clarify meaning or demonstrate possibilities in certain examples. But especially as a beginner, it can also obscure meaning, especially when the English word-for-word translation can be interpreted to mean something else. _À la fois_ is literally _at the time_, perhaps suggesting the same meaning as _then_ (= _alors_), but it means really _at the same time_.

Comment: Often, the usefulness of a dictionary, bilingual or not, is in its ability to explain expressions with relatively non-obvious meanings, like _avoir beau de_, that can’t be parsed literally.

Comment: I disagree with the closing votes here. Even if it may sound weird to ask for literal translations, the question is clear (even more now that the title has been changed) and legit.

Comment: @Reyedy I VTCed more because the motivation seemed unclear to me, after OP's clarification. If I wanted the literal word-for-word translation of a phrase, I could probably create those myself with a bit of guesswork and locating the entries for the individual words in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither natif speaker of English nor of French. If I misunderstood your question I apologize. For me (based on my experience with learning French and German using English textbooks) is not so useful to learn literal translations (at least in the begining). I prefer to learn set expressions as they are, i.e. fixed. Example:

> Je m'appelle Jean Dupont.

The one-to-one translation of this phrase is

> I called myself Jean Dupont.

But I think is better to learn it as the equivalent of

> My name is Jean Dupont.

Another example:

> Faire la grasse matinée

Faire la grasse matinée literally means to have a fat morning. It actually means to sleep in:

> J’ai trop bu hier soir, alors aujourd’hui, j’ai fait la grasse matinée.
>
> I drank too much last night, so today I slept in.

Yet another:

> Ça va ?

Literally: "it goes"; compare English how's it going? or German wie geht's?.

Comment: Back in the days before the Internet, I was reading a book for some French class, and I came across the phrase *le jeu ne vaut pas la chandelle*, which I didn't understand at all. I looked it up in my French dictionary and they gave the translation *the game's not worth the candle* (the idiom does exist in English, but I didn't know it). This was truly unhelpful.