# Difficulty in Je vais?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, vocabulaire, auxiliaires

Je vais au cinéma
Translate as I will to the cinema.
How does it mean I will go to the cinema when we have not used French word for go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Aller* can be used as a semi-auxiliary verb to express an action in the future, but it must be followed by the verb that expresses the future action or state in question, even if it is also *aller*. Otherwise, it is used in the sense of *to go*. *Je vais au cinéma* expresses that the narrator is going (or that he goes) to the cinema. To express that the narrator *will* go to the cinema, one must instead write *Je vais aller au cinéma*.

It is not always helpful to define words [in isolation](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/42142/4082), especially with the aid of a platform such as Google Translate that does not give much context, when we are concerned with a word with multiple meanings. It is more helpful to consult [a bilingual dictionary](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/aller/2362) that will also give you examples of usage that will help contextualize meaning.

Comment: Je vais au  cinéma is most likely: I'm going to the movies. I will go=intention, is j'irai au  cinéma. //I'm going to go to the movies, Je vais aller au x.

Comment: @Lambie The present tense in French is used both for habitual and for continuous actions. *Je vais au cinéma régulièrement. I regularly go to the movies. Aujourd'hui, je vais au cinéma. Today, I'm going to the movies.* And while you're right that the future tense *irai* can be used, eventuality is often expressed using *aller* as an auxiliary alongside an infinitive verb in spoken French. But I wouldn't say there is an exact one to one equivalence between "will go to" and "vais aller".

Comment: @Domino I never said that vais aller is will. **I am saying it is not**. vais aller can be two things: "going to go" or "going" **used as future**. But will as in will go has to be j'irai.

Answer (score 1):

The French word for go, the infinitive form, is the verb **aller**, and it is irregular.

**Verbs in French are conjugated**:
Present Tense
**Je vais**
Tu vas
Il/elle va

Nous allons
Vous allez
Ils/elles vont

Je vais au cinéma. = Translation: I'm going to the movies (cinema).
OR
Je vais au cinéma [toutes les semaines]. = Translation: I go to the movies (cinema) [every week].

I **will go** to the cinema. in French would be: **J'irai au cinéma**.

The future tense is conjugated like this:

J'irai [I will go]
Tu iras [He will go, etc.]
Il/elle ira
Nous irons
Vous irez
Ils/Elles iront

Comment: I did not understand your answer sir

Comment: French has only one present tense (je vais): English has two present tenses. I go and I'm going.=present simple and present progressive. Therefore, je vais can be either one. It depends on the context.

Comment: I am trying to understand you sir but am new pls don’t mind

Comment: I think you might want to look up what a conjugation is in French. For example: the verb aller. English does not have conjugations like French.

Comment: Ok sir merci beacoup

Comment: Three present tense translations in English: "I go, I'm going, I do go."  More if you include present perfect.  As you said, context.

Comment: @livresque There is no reason for a basic answer to include emphatic forms like: I do go or the translation of simple present in French by present perfect in situations like Je x depuis y.